# A unexpected div coming when I hover social icon

Tags: html, css, wordpress

When I'm hover my wordpress site social icon a unexpected div coming top of my icon. I was try to find the icon's class but I faild. can anyone help?
[image]

My website link is : https://www.picco.com.ua/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `tooltip` class and the tooltip shall not appear.

```
<a href="http://" target="_blank" data-label="Facebook"  rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" class="icon button circle is-outline facebook" title="Ми на  Facebook"></a>

<a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" data-label="Instagram" class="icon button circle is-outline  instagram" title="Слідкуйте за Нами на Instagram">
```